# Search and highlight in html with multiple keywords as a single string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, string

In JavaScript, by given a html string with tags like:
**This** *string* has **different** *fonts*.

```
<b>This</b>
<i>string</i>
<span style="background-color: rgb(212, 239, 181);">has</span>
<b>different</b>
<i>fonts</i>.
```

When user searches for a search term with multiple words like "different fonts".

How can I add highlighting to make the html string look like:

```
<b>This</b>
<i>string</i>
<span style="background-color: rgb(212, 239, 181);">has</span>
<span class="highlight">
    <b>different</b>
    <i>fonts</i>
</span>.
```

Please note that the search term is treated as a single string as if the words are in a quote, so I cannot search and highlight each word individually.

Comment: Do you mean the browser's built in search or some search system that you've already implemented? You need to be clearer.

Comment: I have a backend that does the search and will return the messages that has a match. The client has to do the highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize innerHTML + str.replace in Javascript

Start by placing a div around your content.

```
<div id='content'>
```

Set the content to a variable in Javascript.

```
var xyz = document.getElementById("content").innerHTML;
```

Explode the users search into an array and use Javascripts str.replace to filter through the content variable.

```
var needle = document.getElementById("needle").innerHTML;
var splitArray = str.split(" ");
for (var i = 0; i < splitArray.length; i++) {
    /* code below mentioned later */
    xyz = str.replace("<span class='highlight'>" + splitArray[i] + "</span>", splitArray[i]);

}
```

set the replace  text to:

```
"<span class='highlight'>" + /* needle (see above) */ + "</span>"
```

To keep them consecutive, go through the xyz string and replace the span tags with 3 character replacements:

```
var replaceS = xyz.replace("</span>", "~/S");
var replaceS = replaceS.replace("<span class='bold'>", "~/B");
```

Then loop through the string using indexOf. If there is a split array that has an index of the previous split array.length + 7 then you know it is consecutive. The 7 comes from the space between the words + the 3 character replacement you made for the start and end spans: 7 = 3 + 1 + 3

```
var countR = 0;
// CREATE A LOOP HERE 
    var indxStr = replaceS.indexOf(splitArray[0],countR);
    if (replaceS.indexOf(splitArray[1] == (indxStr.length + 7) {
        // good so far!
    } else { 
        // get the previous index and add one to it (so that we do not repeat)
        countR = replaceS.indexOf(indxStr) + 1;
    }
// END YOUR LOOP HERE
```

Where I put "CREATE YOUR LOOP HERE" you want loop so that you can find multiple occurrences of your string (indexOf only gets the first, that is why we used the countR variable to avoid the previous search). The "good so far" comment is to continue on this same style of loop, this loop will only handle 2 words "different fonts" should there be 3 like "has different fonts" then you will need a loop that counts per word ->

```
for (var q = 0; q < splitArray.length; q++) {
    if (q > 1) {
        if (replaceS.indexOf(splitArray[q] == (splitArray[q - 1].length + 7) {

        }
    }
} else {
    // use original code above with splitArray[1] and indxStr
}
// etc~
```

Comment: I haven't test your code but I think it doesn't meet my requirement because the search terms should be treated as a single string. In my case when user search "different fonts", the words "different" and "fonts" should not be highlighted individually if they are not together.

Comment: Do you want the words "different" and "fonts" to hold their bold and italic characteristics on top of being highlighted?

Comment: Yes all existing html tags should remain.